# Sending email to a gmail contact list using a Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Picked up some code from this answer:

[Email a group and not individual addresses with Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538689/email-a-group-and-not-individual-addresses-with-google-app-script/52971918#52971918)

Seems to be working but I'm having this problem with the code.  When I substitute emails for the send line... I get the following:

```
Message details
Invalid email: [L<?>;@11773e2
```

However, the Browser box msg for the email_list has the proper emails.

The code is as follows:

```
var email_list = []; 
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('TESTING').getContacts();

Browser.msgBox(contacts); 

for(var i in contacts){
  email_list.push(contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail());
}

Browser.msgBox(email_list);
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: email_list, 
  subject: "SUBJECT",
  htmlBody: html2,
  inlineImages:emailImages});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MailApp.sendEmail` method expects `to` key's value to be a single string(composed of a list of emails separated by a `,`), while yours is a array. That might be the problem. Try `toString()` or `join()`:

```
email_list.join();
```

If that's not the case, You'd need to examine all emails in the list for any invalids.

Comment: Perfecto and thanks so much -- did the trick.  Thought it might be the case but I'm not much of a programmer to begin with .. and usually its in R.